# How to install Orchard 1.7.2 on IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, orchardcms

I downloaded orchard deployment package. The moment I click on import in IIS,

I land-up with this error:

[image: enable32bitAppOnWin64]

It is likely, I have to alter some config key in deployment package. Q. Can you please help me with this issue? I am using IIS 7.5 on windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uncheck below checkbox to fix the issue.
I hope it would help some one!

[image]